# ActiveAdmin error pushing to heroku, existing config built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

When I push my rails 4 app to Heroku, I receive the following fatal rake error:

> You're trying to register ActiveAdmin::Comment as Comment, but the existing ActiveAdmin::Resource config was built for Comment!

I have a Comment model which has an ActiveAdmin file like this:

```
# /app/admin/comment.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
end
```

An ActiveAdmin migration creates the following active_admin_comments table. I am wondering if this might be related to the conflict, but I am not sure.

```
class CreateActiveAdminComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :active_admin_comments do |t|
      t.string :namespace
      t.text   :body
      t.string :resource_id,   :null => false
      t.string :resource_type, :null => false 
      t.references :author, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :active_admin_comments, [:namespace]
    add_index :active_admin_comments, [:author_type, :author_id]
    add_index :active_admin_comments, [:resource_type, :resource_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :active_admin_comments
  end
end
```

I did have ActiveAdmin working fine on Heroku before this, including both of the files above. I cannot think of what has changed since the last push that could affect the Comment model. Any points of direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It can be confusing to not be able to register your own model named Comment because of the default comments that come with Active Admin. We should register ActiveAdmin::Comments as something other than Comments. see here https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/301

Comment: can u tell which version of active admin u r using, I think this issue is solved in latest version.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding 
`"config.allow_comments = false"` to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` and this solved the issue for me. I am running version (1.0.0.pre) from git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git